# How is the label of Form Field linked with the field in PDF Fill-able form? How to retriving the COSObject or COSBase into understandable format?

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

How is the label of Form Field linked with the field in PDF Fill-able form?

I am trying to extract the label of the field in pdf form. Currently I am using pdfbox. There is no means to get the label directly from PDField object. How to convert the COSObject or COSBase into an understandable format. Is the details about the label of the field located in the COSBase of that PDField? I am currently using Pdfbox.

Comment: Did you try the PrintFields example program from the source code? If yes, what is the information that is missing? The best would be that you describe it with a link to some publicly available pdf form.

Comment: Yes I have tried that program. The name that is provided in getFullyQualifiedName() is not the label of the field. I need to get the label name. What I  predict is the label name will be available some where in the COSObject. How to extract it?

Comment: http://www.uspto.gov/sites/default/files/patents/process/file/efs/guidance/updated_IDS.pdf . In pdf of these type, the FullyQualifiedName or PartialName has no relation with the label, and it is completely different. Then from the data we extracted we wont be able to know the original field to which this extracted data indicate.

Comment: Try also the command line application PDFDebugger. It shows what's available. If you don't see it, then it doesn't exist.

Comment: There is no forced connection between the label of a field (example "Name:" left of the field (or above, or below, or somewhere else…)) and the field itself in PDF. However, if the PDF has a structure (as it would do if it had been made accessible), such a connection is made and could be read out, from the structure.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr Thanks for the suggestion. PDFDebugger seems to be helpful